# Android checkbox checked at random position in Listview

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I know it is common problem with Listview and Checkbox, I am try from 2 days but it is not solving, so I raised question here.

I had list of items in Arraylist, like 15(supposed) items. Inside listview there is a checkbox, by default 11(supposed) checkbox is comes checked by API (JSON Response)
 But I have to show only 5 items checked. I tried alot but not find any solution.

I had create a dummy list that contain 11 items that comes from API and save 5 items from original arraylist. Here is code to match items in listview and save this list in Shared Preference.

> Adapter class inside getViwe() function

```
 List<SaveOrderId> getIds = prefManager.getNewOrders(context);

 for (int i = 0; i < getIds.size(); i++) {

  String idget = getIds.get(i).getOrderId();// it get ids from save list

  for (int j = 0; j < newOrders.size(); j++) {

      String bot = newOrders.get(j).getId(); // id from orginal list

      if (bot.equalsIgnoreCase(idget)) {

          showErrorLog(TAG, String.format("Bot id is %s and Saved Id is %s", bot, idget));

          myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(true);

          final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
          if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
              myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_green));
          } else {
              myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_green));
          }
          myViewHolder.txt_check_status.setText("ADDED");

      } else {
          getPerspective().showErrorLog(TAG, "Not Equal");

          myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(false);
          final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
          if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
              myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_dark_gray));
          } else {
              myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_dark_gray));
          }
          myViewHolder.txt_check_status.setText("ADD FOR PAYMENT");
      }
  }
}
```

Adapter class code is here

```
public class NewOrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private String TAG = "Current Order";
private Context context;
private List<NewOrder> newOrders;
private MyOrders myOrders;
private Perspective perspective;
private double total = 0.0;
private PrefManager prefManager;
// private List<SaveOrderId> ids;
private boolean isAdded = false;
private List<SaveOrderId> papa = new ArrayList<>();

private LayoutInflater inflater;


public NewOrderAdapter(Context context, List<NewOrder> newOrders, MyOrders myOrders) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newOrders = newOrders;
    this.myOrders = myOrders;
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this.context);
    total = myOrders.total;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // ids = new ArrayList<>();
}


private void showDeleteAlert(final String orderId) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder1.setTitle("Alert");
    builder1.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.delete_order));
    builder1.setCancelable(false);
    builder1.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    myOrders.cancelOrder(orderId);
                }
            });

    builder1.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return newOrders.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return newOrders.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder myViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        myViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_new_order_row, parent, false);

        myViewHolder.img_delete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_delete);
        myViewHolder.add_payment = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_payment);
        myViewHolder.txt_topic_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_topic_name);
        myViewHolder.txt_order_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_order_id);
        myViewHolder.txt_delivery_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_delivery_date);
        myViewHolder.txt_words = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_words);
        myViewHolder.txt_order_status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_order_status);
        myViewHolder.txt_offer_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_offer_price);
        myViewHolder.txt_price_tag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price_tag);
        myViewHolder.txt_check_status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_check_status);
        myViewHolder.txt_total_amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_total_amount);
        myViewHolder.txt_payment_status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_payment_status);
        myViewHolder.txt_paid_amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_paid_amount);
        myViewHolder.txt_view_more = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_more);
        myViewHolder.txt_order_tag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_order_tag);
        myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_layout_checked);
        myViewHolder.layout_payment_details = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_payment_details);
        myViewHolder.layout_paid = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_paid);

        convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
    } else {
        myViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    try {
        myViewHolder.txt_topic_name.setText(newOrders.get(position).getTopic());

        if (newOrders.get(position).getOrder_code().equalsIgnoreCase("Not allotted")
                || newOrders.get(position).getOrder_code().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_tag.setText(context.getString(R.string.temp_id));
            myViewHolder.txt_order_id.setText(newOrders.get(position).getId());
        } else {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_tag.setText(context.getText(R.string.order_code_));
            myViewHolder.txt_order_id.setText(newOrders.get(position).getOrder_code());
        }

        myViewHolder.txt_words.setText(String.format("%s Words", newOrders.get(position).getWords()));
        myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setText(newOrders.get(position).getProject_status());
        myViewHolder.txt_offer_price.setText(String.format("%s %s %s", newOrders.get(position).getPrice_label(), newOrders.get(position).getSymbol(), newOrders.get(position).getDue()));
        myViewHolder.txt_price_tag.setText(newOrders.get(position).getPayment_label());
        myViewHolder.txt_total_amount.setText(String.format("%s %s", newOrders.get(position).getSymbol(), newOrders.get(position).getCost()));

        String projectStatus = newOrders.get(position).getProject_status();

        if (projectStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("in process")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orange));
        } else if (projectStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("delivered")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green_text));
        } else if (projectStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("pending")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red));
        } else if (projectStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("feedback")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.feedback));
        } else if (projectStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("checked")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.checked));
        } else if (projectStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("ready")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.ready));
        } else if (projectStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("delivered draft")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.delivered_draft));
        } else if (projectStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Payment Refund")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.payment_refund));
        } else if (projectStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Not Accepted")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_order_status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
        }

        String payStatus = newOrders.get(position).getPay_status();

        if (payStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_payment_status.setText(payStatus);
            myViewHolder.txt_payment_status.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        }

        if (payStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Partially paid")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_payment_status.setText(payStatus);
            myViewHolder.txt_payment_status.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        }

        if (payStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Complete")) {
            myViewHolder.txt_payment_status.setText(payStatus);
            myViewHolder.txt_payment_status.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_text));
        }

        double paidAmt = newOrders.get(position).getPaid();

        if (paidAmt == 0) {
            myViewHolder.layout_paid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            myViewHolder.layout_paid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.txt_paid_amount.setText(String.format("%s %s", newOrders.get(position).getSymbol(), newOrders.get(position).getPaid()));
        }

        final String gateway_name = newOrders.get(position).getPayment_gateway_name();

        myViewHolder.add_payment.setEnabled(false);


        if (gateway_name.equalsIgnoreCase(prefManager.getCurrencyGateway())) {

            if (!newOrders.get(position).getPay_status().equalsIgnoreCase("Complete")) {

                double dueAmt = newOrders.get(position).getDue();
                myViewHolder.layout_payment_details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (dueAmt != 0) {


                    List<SaveOrderId> getIds = prefManager.getNewOrders(context);

                    for (int i = 0; i < getIds.size(); i++) {

                        String idget = getIds.get(i).getOrderId();

                        for (int j = 0; j < newOrders.size(); j++) {
                            String bhoot = newOrders.get(j).getId();
                            if (bhoot.equalsIgnoreCase(idget)) {

                              showErrorLog(TAG, String.format("Bhoot id is %s and Saved Id is %s", bhoot, idget));

                                myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(true);

                                final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                                if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                    myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_green));
                                } else {
                                    myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_green));
                                }
                                myViewHolder.txt_check_status.setText("ADDED");

                            } else {
                                showErrorLog(TAG, "Not Equal");

                                myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(false);
                                final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                                if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                    myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_dark_gray));
                                } else {
                                    myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_dark_gray));
                                }
                                myViewHolder.txt_check_status.setText("ADD FOR PAYMENT");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                myViewHolder.layout_payment_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(false);
            final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_dark_gray));
            } else {
                myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_dark_gray));
            }
            myViewHolder.txt_check_status.setText("ADD FOR PAYMENT");
        }

        //  prefManager.saveNewOrders(context, ids);

        myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //  myViewHolder.add_payment.performClick();

                double dueAmt = newOrders.get(position).getDue();

                if (dueAmt == 0.00) {
                   showErrorLog("Adapter", "No Order");
                    myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(false);
                   showAlert(context.getString(R.string.alert_header_warning), context.getString(R.string.alert_3_msg), "Ok");
                } else {

                    if (!myViewHolder.add_payment.isChecked()) {

                        int size = prefManager.getNewOrders(context).size();

                        if (size < 6) {
                            String dis = newOrders.get(position).getId().concat(newOrders.get(position).getTopic());

                            if (size == 0) {

                                String orderid = newOrders.get(position).getId();
                                String payName = newOrders.get(position).getPayment_gateway_name();
                                SaveOrderId saveOrderId = new SaveOrderId(orderid, payName);

                                papa.add(saveOrderId);
                                prefManager.saveNewOrders(context, papa);

                                myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(true);

                                myViewHolder.txt_check_status.setText("ADDED");

                                String sym = newOrders.get(position).getSymbol();

                                final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                                if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                    myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_green));
                                } else {
                                    myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_green));
                                }
                                total = total + newOrders.get(position).getDue();

                                myOrders.setPrice(sym, total, payName, dis);
                            } else {
                                String orderid = newOrders.get(position).getId();
                                String payName = newOrders.get(position).getPayment_gateway_name();
                                List<SaveOrderId> getIds = prefManager.getNewOrders(context);

                                for (int i = 0; i < getIds.size(); i++) {
                                    String name = getIds.get(i).getGateWayName();
                                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(payName)) {
                                        isAdded = true;
                                        break;
                                    } else {
                                        isAdded = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (isAdded) {
                                    myViewHolder.txt_check_status.setText("ADDED");
                                    String sym = newOrders.get(position).getSymbol();
                                    final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                                    if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                        myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_green));
                                    } else {
                                        myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_green));
                                    }
                                    total = total + newOrders.get(position).getDue();
                                    myOrders.setPrice(sym, total, payName, dis);
                                    myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(true);
                                    SaveOrderId saveOrderId = new SaveOrderId(orderid, payName);
                                    papa.add(saveOrderId);
                                    prefManager.saveNewOrders(context, papa);
                                } else {
                                    showAlert(context.getString(R.string.alert_header_notic), context.getString(R.string.alert_1_msg), "Ok");
                                    myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(false);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                          showMessage("Maximum limit reached.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        List<SaveOrderId> getIds = prefManager.getNewOrders(context);
                        String name = newOrders.get(position).getPayment_gateway_name();
                        String dis = newOrders.get(position).getId().concat(newOrders.get(position).getTopic());

                        if (getIds.size() != 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < getIds.size(); i++) {
                                String abc = getIds.get(i).getGateWayName();
                                if (abc.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                                    getIds.remove(i);
                                    prefManager.saveNewOrders(context, getIds);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (prefManager.getNewOrders(context).size() == 0) {
                            papa.clear();
                            prefManager.clearOrderIds(context);
                        }

                        String sym = newOrders.get(position).getSymbol();
                        myViewHolder.txt_check_status.setText("ADD FOR PAYMENT");

                        myViewHolder.add_payment.setChecked(false);

                        final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                        if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_dark_gray));
                        } else {
                            myViewHolder.txt_layout_checked.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.shape_rect_rounder_corner3_bg_dark_gray));
                        }

                        total = total - newOrders.get(position).getDue();
                        myOrders.setPrice(sym, total, name, dis);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {

    TextView txt_topic_name, txt_order_id, txt_delivery_date, txt_words, txt_order_status, txt_offer_price, txt_price_tag, txt_check_status,
            txt_total_amount, txt_payment_status, txt_paid_amount, txt_view_more, txt_order_tag;
    CheckBox add_payment;
    ImageView img_delete;
    RelativeLayout txt_layout_checked, layout_payment_details;
    LinearLayout layout_paid;
}
```

}

Problem is that, all 11 items showing checked. Please help.

Comment: Post your full adapter implementation. By the way, why you are using list view. Use recycler view.

Comment: I am not sure with business logic from your code. Further, make sure that you have i*j items in the list and check from log that all 11  items is coming in if block or not because the basic condition is implemented there correctly. It would be good if you send the adpater class code snippet here.

Comment: Check in your XML, if your CheckBox is `checked=true` or not.

Comment: @RafiqulHasan, at first time i used RecyclerView but it having same issue so I switch to Listview

Comment: @RafiqulHasan Adapter code is add, pls check

Comment: @HariNJha Adapter code added.

Comment: I per an overview of the adapter class, I guess the implemetation of overall flow is good but the issue is in the loop section. I think there is some logical flaw in the concept. Can you please elaborate what is PrefManager, why inner loop and what you want to do exactly there?

Comment: PrefManager is class to save data in shared preference, I had save 5 orderId in that class's function.